# What does this mean: TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am a newbie, following a tutorial about modern webdev workflow. I get this error message in my console. `TypeError: dest.on is not a function`
I know, there are related questions and answers here. But I don't understand them. Because I don't know what "dest.on" is related to and what does it do.
This is the code so far:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var autoprefixer = require("auto-prefixer");
var imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task("css", function() {
  return gulp
    .src("src/sass/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
      })
    )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./maps"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"));
});
```

**Could anyone explain, what the error message means and how I can solve this particular problem?** I am sorry for the redundancy but I found no solution in the existing answers.

Edit::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Maybe it helps adding the package.json

```js
{
  "name": "sitepointresponsivewebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-prefixer": "^0.4.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5"
  }
}
```

This is the complete terminal error message

```
Beratungs-MacBook-Pro-2:sitepointResponsiveWebsite Beratung1$ gulp css
[14:04:02] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/gulpfile.js
[14:04:02] Starting 'css'...
[14:04:02] 'css' errored after 12 ms
[14:04:02] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:564:8)
    at /Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/gulpfile.js:13:6
    at taskWrapper (/Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:396:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:409:12)
    at asyncRunner (/Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Comment: You don't have `dest.on` anywhere in your code...

Comment: If the error mentions code that is not present in the code you written it probably means you passed some function the wrong value. Ie some function you called was expecting an object with an `on` property but you passed something else like a number/string instead

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace to your question?

Comment: search all your code block for *des* and check if you are binding any event to it or any plugin. basically that not available.

Comment: just for clarification : we have a 'on' in the sass part and a dest in the last lien can you try temporary removing either one of those to narrow it down ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With unfamiliar error messages like this, the stack trace is usually the most helpful.

```
at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:564:8)
at /Users/Beratung1/Desktop/sitepointResponsiveWebsite/gulpfile.js:13:6
```

The error is happening in the `pipe()` method in readable-stream. `dest` is the name of the first argument to `pipe()`; the fact that "dest.on" does not exist means that something you passed to `pipe()` is not actually a stream.

The second stack frame refers to line 13, which is this `pipe()` call:

```
.pipe(
  autoprefixer({
    browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
  })
)
```

So, the return value of autoprefixer() is not a stream.

`autoprefixer` is:

```
var autoprefixer = require("auto-prefixer");
```

Looking at that module on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-prefixer. Looks weird, it definitely isn't a stream API though.

The *real* autoprefixer module is called `autoprefixer`, no dash. You can use it together with gulp-postcss as described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer#gulp

```
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

// .. etc ..
  .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({
    // .. options ..
  }) ]))
```